# NEXTJS :TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, next.js

I am new to nextjs ,While  upgrading nextjs from v13 to v14.1.0 i am facing below error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
To remove above error I  modify the code   backend code from CommonJs  module to  ES module
Now when I run the application, it throws below error

TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi6pX.png)

```
Document.js file
================
import '@babel/polyfill'
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Document from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage
     try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props =>
            sheet.collectStyles(
              <>
                <Head>
                  <script
                    type="module”
                  />
                </Head>
                <App {...props} />
              </>
            ),
        })
      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      }
    } finally {
      sheet.seal()
    }
  }
}
```

i upgrade the nodejs
present i am  using nodejs v18.17.1 i upgrade it to v20.10.0
yarn v - 1.22.19
i removed nodemodules and installed it again
but still trowing error